# Password Auth Condition On Delete Button C#

Tags: c#, function

I have a delete button, which removes the records from the database.
I need to add a "Enter your password" popup form in order to prevent users from deleting by accident. Only Admin who has the password will be able to delete the data.

Here is my button code:

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("If you are not a System Administrator Please do not touch.", "Remove Row", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {


                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("ContactDeleteByID", sqlCon);
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PhoneBookID", PhoneBookID);
                sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Deleted Successfully");
                Clear();
                GridFill();
            }
        }

        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Row Not Removed", "Remove Row", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is your question how to request that password? Do you want to use a standard dialog box or a custom form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create some new windows for authorization and use
`Window.ShowDialog()` method

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var auth = new AuthWindow();

        auth.ShowDialog();

        if (auth.IsAdmin)
        {
            //do smth
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Row Not Removed", "Remove Row", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        
    }
```

AuthWindow.cs

```
    private void btnOk_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        isAdmin = tb.Text == "SomePass";
        this.Hide();
    }
```